# I'm writing an image to SD Card in blackberry simulator, how can I clear it for testing?

Tags: java, image, blackberry, sd-card

I usually press 'clean' and it gets rid of all the persistent data but the image file isn't changing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, then try following steps:

> - On the **Run** menu, click **Run Configurations**.
> - In **Simulator** tab check "Clear SD Card on startup".

[image: Simulator tab]

Answer (score 1):

clean.bat takes long time to execute. Just delete all *.dmp files in simulator folder. It will clear all persistent store data, including sdcard. It will preserve all installed cod files.